# 3ware Raid Migration 9650SE

Tags: hardware-raid, raid1, 3ware

I'm trying to migrate a single disk on a 9650SE 4LPML to a RAID 1.  I'm trying to use 3dm2 to accomplish this, but the only options it will allow me to migrate to is either RAID 0 or RAID 10.  I only have 2 drives on the controller at the moment, so why it's giving me an option for RAID 10 - I don't know.  I also tried doing it through the cards BIOS, but there doesn't seem to be an option to migrate.

Controller Summary

`0      9650SE-4LPML    L326010B1420305     FE9X 4.08.00.006    2.26.02.012     OK`

Drive Information:

`0      WDC WD5000AAKX-001CA0   465.76 GB   SATA    0   --      0   OK

1   WDC WD5000AAKX-753CA1   465.76 GB   SATA    1   --  --  OK`

If it makes any difference:

OS: Ubuntu 10.04 Server
 / Kernel: 2.6.32-38-server

Anyone have any ideas to get me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Edit: Success

Canned 3dm2 and went with tw_cli

`//router> /c0/u0 migrate type=raid1 disk=1
Sending migration message to /c0/u0 ... Done.`

Answer (score 0):

In hardware controller parlance, RAID-10 is the same as a mirror - except it also allows you to stripe them into RAID-10.

So yes, you want RAID-10; with two disks, this automatically becomes a mirror.

Comment: I just gave that a try, and this is the error: `(0x0B:0x001A): Invalid number of drives : Failed to start Migrate on unit 01`

Comment: If the controller has no support to create a degraded array, you need both drives to start with.